# How can I plot two lines sharing data and a single y column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

So I have this VERY simple assignment from economy class, where we have to plot this offer/demand table:

| QD | QO | PREU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 120 | 100 |
| 20 | 60 | 80 |
| 30 | 30 | 60 |
| 40 | 15 | 40 |
| 50 | 0 | 20 |

And in the book, shows how "preu" (price) is plotted on the Y axis, while quantity (both offered quantity and demanded quantity) is on the X axis.

The thing is, Excel won't allow me to plot two "Price" data subsets and assign them both the quantity columns in order to have two good ol' classic x-shaped supply/demand graphics. I'm literally losing my mind. The solution must be simple since I'm new to Excel but can't think of it.

Of course, the problem is solved if we swap the axis, but I'd like to know if it's possible to plot it as the book states.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with maths. Maybe a quick hand drawn graphic would give us an idea of what you wish? Good luck!

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if the following Imgur link works:

https://imgur.com/a/TUTZRte

Comment: One of the lines would be the quantity supplied and the other one would be the quantity demanded. X-axis represents quantity, as a whole, and Y-axis represents price.

Comment: Try removing `QD` from the first cell and creating a line chart

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad check it out, only one line appears for both quantity ranged. I need two, each compared to the price:

https://imgur.com/a/CDTQwUe

Answer (score 0):

**There's probably a very better solution, but this is how I did it on Excel 2013.**

Result:
[image]

Preu is in the Y column (neglect the 120 value which has been added and you can remove).

QD is in Blue, QO in Orange, their values are in axle X.

**Procedure:**

- **First put Preu column in first column and separate (to be clear) QO**, you'll make the first graph with Preu and QD only.

[image]

- **Then right click on the graph, Select Data, Add** to add the second serie. Carefully pick up the proper ranges for QO.

[image]

- **Click OK then OK - you're done.**

Hoping it's this you wish and that could help you?